# How do I make a row of divs with rows?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to make a row of divs, where each div has two rows.  I have the following code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Row of Divs</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="inline">
    <div class="block">
        <p>
            ABC
            <br>
            DEF
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>
            GHI
            <br>
            JKL
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>
            MNO
            <br>
            PQR
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>
            STU
            <br>
            VWX
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
div.inline{
    display: inline;
}

div.block{
    display: block;
}
```

So I want the following output:

```
ABC    GHI    MNO    STU
DEF    JKL    PQR    VWX
```

But I get the folling output:

```
ABC 
DEF

GHI
JKL

MNO 
PQR

STU
VWX
```

How can I fix my code to stay inline the as a row of rows, as shown above?

Comment: Can you fix your output values to match? The letters it's returning aren't the same...

Comment: @Evorlor p.s. it's not necessary to set the parent to `display: inline` as you can see i removed that on all my demos below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ar97yzqv/1/
CSS:

```
.inline{
        display: inline;
    }

    .block{
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `.block` to be a block element, therefore making a full width element that clears everything from both sides.

You need to set this to be an `inline` or `inline-block` element and it should work as expected.

```css
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Row of Divs</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="inline">
    <div class="block">
      <p>
        ABC
        <br>DEF
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>
        GHI
        <br>JKL
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>
        MNO
        <br>PQR
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p>
        STU
        <br>VWX
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: much appreciated :) in case ur curious tho, i green check marked the other answer because it was easier for me to edit and experiment with. if i could, id green check mark u too

Comment: That we are it's best praticse to put out examples like this with the embeded code editor since we don't know if Jsfiddle will go down one day..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways as follows.

Use [**`inline-block`**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxgbo1ch/) *(recommended)*

```
.block { display: inline-block; } /*child*/
```

OR [**`float`**](http://jsfiddle.net/bg0aejqo/)

```
.block { float: left; } /*child*/
```

OR [**`flex`**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbob6mh3/)

```
.inline { display: flex; } /*parent*/
```

OR [**`table + table-cell`**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9L4Lty1/)

```
.inline { display: table; } /*parent*/
.block { display: table-cell; } /*child*/
```